# Reload beanstalkd configuration without restaring

Tags: service, ubuntu-12.04, beanstalkd, beanstalkc

Is there a way to reload the beanstalkd config without actually restarting beanstalkd?

When I use `sudo service beanstalkd restart` or `sudo service beanstalkd force-reload` it clears all the queues.

(Yes, in the future I *will* run it in persistent mode)

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a signal you can send to the Beanstalkd Daemon to reload. For production, the binlog is very highly suggested, since any crash/exit would drop all the jobs because they are only in memory.

Comment: Yes, that's what I also found out (the hard way :p).