# Stop or restart beanstalkd manually on command line

Tags: command, beanstalkd

Beanstalkd is running on my Ubuntu VPS. I don't know how to stop or shut down the beandstalkd server. I want to stop the server manually on the command line.

I've found monitoring tools and a configurations script, but no commands for the commandline.

Comment: I've found a script. But it's not clear to me: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/beanstalk-talk/6VHaGN5Svpg. In the file /etc/init.d/beanstalkd contains a variable DIETIME. It's out commented. Will the server wake up or restart after getting a job?

Comment: Restart is possible by this commands:sudo service beanstalkd restart or sudo service beanstalkd force-reload. Thanks to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944879/reload-beanstalkd-configuration-without-restaring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beanstalkd is normally run with the standard OS-level tools (so, on Ubuntu, *upstart*). There are a number of example configuration scripts for LaunchD, systemD and Upstart in the [Beanstalkd repo](https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd/tree/master/adm).

For an Ubuntu system, you would copy the [Upstart .conf file](https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd/blob/master/adm/upstart/beanstalkd.conf), making any required tweaks to the command line you need (to enable the binary log, for example) and drop it into the `/etc/init/` directory. Then the usual start, restart, stop & status commands would be able to control the Beanstalkd daemon, and it could be auto-started on bootup.

If it's not already under upstart control, then you can simply kill the process, like anything else, by finding the process ID (`pgrep -lf beanstalkd`).